# google static map with Overlay image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

How can I pass overlay map image with image bounds in static map service?

I have an image which I want to overlay on map at certain position, looks like current static map image service doesn't provide any parameter to pass that.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. On static maps you can't send add custom overlays like in the javascript api. But maybe you can consider this as work around, you [Add custom markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers) on your map URL.

> You can use up to five unique custom icons per request. This limitation does not mean that you are limited to only 5 marked locations on your map. Each unique icon may be used with more than one markers location on your map.
>
> Icon format:
>
> Icon images may be in PNG, JPEG or GIF formats, though PNG is recommended.
> Icons may be up to 4096 pixels maximum size (64x64 for square images).